# How to save dates in local timezone to db with rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I have Rails3 application with model user and field expires_at created like this:

```
t.column :expires_at, :timestamp
```

In my database (postgresql) it has type:

```
timestamp without timezone
```

The problem is when I call:

```
@user.expires_at = Time.now
@user.save
```

it is saved into database with UTC timezone (my local time is UTC + 1:00, Warsaw) but I don't want that. I just want to have time with my local timezone saved into the database (2011-03-30 01:29:01.766709, not 2011-03-29 23:29:01.766709)

Can I achieve this using rails3?

Comment: Beware!  If you'll have users across more than one timezone, this'll get messy fast.  I prefer to keep all my times as UTC in the DB, and only convert them to non-UTC for display on the client side (you can convert a time from UTC to the timezone set in a user's OS with a little bit of JavaScript).  Good luck!

Comment: what about database queries when i take input from user?? ActiveRecord convers it to UTC automatically?

Comment: That's a good question, but I doubt it - it would have to know the user's time zone to be able to do the correct conversion.  If you want to store user-supplied dates as UTC, you'll probably have to convert them client-side (urgh).  I've used [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) for my client-side conversions, but I've only done display - I've never accepted dates as input...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For saving time in local timezone to database this has to be set in `application.rb`

```
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you are using Resque. Not sure how to deal with resque.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to use local times on certain columns, rather than as a global setting, then the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html) tells us this:

```
# If your attributes are time zone aware and you desire to skip time zone conversion to the current Time#zone when reading certain attributes then you can do following:

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:written_on]
end
```

(This also skips time zone conversion on writing, not just reading). And you can pass in an array of symbols for multiple attributes.

I am not sure which versions of Rails this was introduced in, though.

Comment: It doesn't seem to skip timezone on writing (i.e. it still converts to UTC), how do you check it? When I query via `psql`, I see all the values converted to UTC, instead of in the original timezone.

Comment: you also need to set `config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false` to prevent conversion to UTC when saving to the database